# Node.js stop playing audio

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, runtime-error

```
var fs = require('fs');
var lame = require('lame');
var Speaker = require('speaker');

var $stream = fs.createReadStream('sounds/test.mp3').pipe(new lame.Decoder).pipe(new Speaker);

setTimeout(function() {
    $stream.close();
}, 5000);

setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('It worked!');
}, 10000);
```

This produces the following output. (Not 'It worked!' as expected.) Is there any way to stop the playing of a audio file?

```
node: pcm.c:1951: snd_pcm_bytes_to_frames: Assertion `pcm' failed.
Abgebrochen (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to work with `.end`, so maybe you aren't supposed to use `close`. Otherwise perhaps there is a bug in the library.

```
$stream.end();
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the reason close doesn't do it is because close is for the downstream, not the upstream.